# Web Worker: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: angular, typescript, importerror, web-worker

Hi I am trying to use a web worker to conduct heavy calculations without freezing the UI. I have an Angular app with typecsript. Following some basic tutorials I am able to create a script for the worker, create a worker and communicate with it. The problem occurs when I try to import anything into the worker.js script.

Here is the code I have:
Service that uses the worker:

```
    var myWorker = new Worker('./path/to/worker.js', {type: 'module'});
    myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(`Message received from worker: ${e.data}`);
    }
    myWorker.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(`Error received from worker: ${e.message}`);
    }
    
    setInterval(async () => {
      var first = Math.random();
      var second = Math.random();
      myWorker.postMessage([first, second]);
    }, 1000);
```

Worker script (worker.js)

```
import * as faceApi from "face-api.js"; //not used in this example, but will be used in the end result

onmessage = function(e) {
  var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

As I already mentioned, communication works perfectly without imports. As soon as I add them, I get the error

> Error received from worker: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I also noticed that when I use Chrome, the message in the worker error is undefined, I can see it though when I switch to Firefox. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you use async (lazy) imports: `await import("face-api.js")`

Comment: @kellys When I add it on top of the script I get 
"await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

When I add it inside the function I get 
"Dynamic module import is disabled or not supported in this context"

Comment: I'm also having this same issue. AFAN, FF doesn't support `{ type: 'module' }` yet. And Chrome won't show me whats is going on too. Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: No, I gave up as WebWorkers don't have access to DOM and in my case it was needed. I managed to use the library that I wanted in the worker but I did it by copying the .js files of the library to the folder where my worker.js script was located. I guess it is not the proper approach :)